# Is there a "clone view" functionality in Qgis like in MapInfo

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, thematic-map

I am currently working in Qgis (2.18.11) and I would like to view mi map window duplicated so I can represent a thematic map with different values in each window and compare both.

I usually do this in MapInfo (Map > Clone view). See the example:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use the **Dockable MirrorMap** plugin which allows you to create multiple canvas windows:

[image: Example]

---

You can download this from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins
```

Comment: It is good, but not exactly what I was looking for. Dockable MirrorMap only draws one layer at a time and changes the scale of the mirrormap when the scale is chankged in the original map.

Comment: @Pescariz - Uncheck the **Render** option so that the image remains static. If you click the plugin icon multiple times, you can create multiple windows :)

Comment: Thanks! I just realised that by checking the lock next to the scale, it remains still too. It's just a pity if a map has many layers, one needs to click and click so many times.

Comment: @Pescariz - Most welcome! Note that the dockable windows display the **canvas**, not necessarily the individual layers. So you can have as many layers as you want shown in each map :)

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the same, but you can duplicate the layer (right click > 'Duplicate') which adds the layer again (as opposed to making a copy) which you can then style in a different way. If you put the layer and its duplicate into a group and then make the group mutually exclusive ( needs a reasonably recent version of QGIS) you can then toggle between the styling options.